# Iteratively build multi-index dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have `n` small dataframes which I combine into one multiindex dataframe.

```
d1 = DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 5, 9],
    ['b', 4, 61],
    ['c', 24, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr11', 'attr22'])

d2 = DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 5, 19],
    ['b', 14, 16],
    ['c', 4, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr21', 'attr22'])

d3 = DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 5, 19],
    ['b', 14, 16],
    ['d', 10, 14],
    ['c', 4, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr21', 'attr22'])
```

How to combine these into one dataframe?

Result:

```
      name attr11 attr21  attr22
d1    a    5    NULL    9
      b    4    NULL    61
      c    24   NULL    9
d2    a    NULL   5    19
      b    NULL   14   16
      c    NULL   4    9
d3    a    NULL   5    19 
      b    NULL   14   16
      c    NULL   4    9
      d    NULL   10   14
```

Comment: Usually some combination of `concat` or `merge` or `join`, but you're going to have to let us know what the result should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can build the `multiindex` after the concatenation. You just need to add a column to each frame with the dataframe id:

```
frames =[d1,d2,d3]
```

Add a column to each frame with the frame id:

```
for x in enumerate(frames):
    x[1]['frame_id'] = 'd'+str(x[0]+1)
```

then concatenate the list of frames and set the index on the desired columns:

```
pd.concat(frames).set_index(['frame_id','name'])
```

Comment: thanks. Can a value (multi-level index) be attached? In my example, `d1`, `d2`, and `d3` so that I can later know what was the value corresponding to `d1`

Comment: thanks. But I get an error in the enumerate section of the code. `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str 
`

Comment: can you post the traceback? Are you calling enumerate on a list of dataframes?

Comment: Working fine now. Thanks. Error was because of typo.